# TimeoutError: Timeout exceeded while waiting for event after click on button in autotest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, puppeteer

Registration on the site consists of three stages. The first step is to provide a name, email address. When you submit the form of the first step, you are redirected to the second step (confirmation by email). The URL changes in the browser, and confirmation email sends to the mail.
For implement the autotest, we decided that we would always register the same email address. For confirmation in the request for this email you will receive a confirmation link. Sample code below.

```
await page.click(btnSignUp)
const [response] = await Promise.all([
   page.waitForResponse((response) =>response.url()===apiURL+'/register'), 
   {timeout: 30 * 1000}
])
const responseData = await response.json()
```

After clicking on the "Register" button, I see the following page (confirm email), but I cannot get a response to the request. I see the response in the terminal when performing an autotest. But I got the error "**TimeoutError: Timeout exceeded while waiting for event**" What is the problem, help me figure it out, please.

Comment: I don't think this is related to the core of your question, but I'm perplexed as to why you're using `Promise.all`, when you have only one async operation to perform. I've never seen anyone pass `{timeout:number}` to `Promise.all` before, and neither [the docs for Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) nor a quick experiment suggest there is any native behavior triggered by such an object.

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching code snippet. You can use that and modify according to your scenario. It helps in dealing with timeout error related issues.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const { scrollPageToBottom } = require('puppeteer-autoscroll-down')

async function scrape () {

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page =  await browser.newPage();

await page.goto("https://twitter.com/elonmusk", {waitUntil: "networkidle2"});

let isLoadingAvailable = true // Your condition-to-stop

while (isLoadingAvailable) {
    try{
        await scrollPageToBottom(page, { size: 250 , delay: 500})
        await page.waitForResponse(
        response => response.url() === 'https://twitter.com/elonmusk' && response.status() === 200
        )

    } catch (ex) {
        continue;
        
    }
    isLoadingAvailable = false // Update your condition-to-stop value
}

console.log("Loading done")
await browser.close();
};
scrape();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
  {
    visible: true,
    waitUntil: "load",
    waitUntil: "networkidle0",
    waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
    waitUntil: "networkidle2",
    timeout: 90 * 1000,
  }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how you have fixed OP's problem

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34122834)